# UIView does not respond to touch event and retuns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiwindow, hittest

I am trying to display a simple custom alert, which is a UIView. The code to display the alert is as follows

```
if let alertController =  try? OKAlertController.getAlertController(message: disclaimerText ?? NSAttributedString(string: ""), actions: [alertActionCancel, alertActionContinue]){
                                alertController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
                                alertController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Multiple threads are called before this and on their completion this code is called. 
The view is displayed correctly, but when I try interacting, I get the following error:

```
[Touch] unexpected nil window in __sendSystemGestureLatentClientUpdate,
                                 _windowServerHitTestWindow: 
                                     <UIWindow: 0x7ff065e031a0; 
                                      frame = (0 0; 414 736); 
                                      autoresize = W+H; 
                                      userInteractionEnabled = NO; 
                                      gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800005d3d0>; 
                                      layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x608000221e80>
                                     >, 
                                 touch:<UITouch: 0x7ff065d75520> 
                                 phase: Stationary 
                                 tap count: 1 
                                 force: 0.000 
                                 window: (null) 
                                 view: (null) 
                                 location in window: {0, 0} 
                                 previous location in window: {0, 0} 
                                 location in view: {0, 0} 
                                 previous location in view: {0, 0}
```

I did try to running the displaying logic on main thread but that did not work. Stackoverflow suggests reinitialising the UIWindow, but that is not the desired behaviour for me.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the class the populates the alert. It is a UIViewController which has a textview inside and two buttons at the bottom.

```
class OKAlertController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private var buttons: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet private weak var labelSeperator: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var textViewMessageDisplayer: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var contraintHeightTextView: NSLayoutConstraint!

    private var alertActions: [OKAlertAction]?

    static private let kMaximumActionCount = 2
    static private let kAlertStoryBoardName = "AlertStoryBoard"

    public class func getAlertController(message: NSAttributedString, actions: [OKAlertAction]) throws -> OKAlertController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: kAlertStoryBoardName, bundle: nil)
        guard let alertController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.GenericScreens.OKALertControllerID) as? OKAlertController else {
            throw OKAlertError.viewLoadingFailed
        }

        if actions.count > OKAlertController.kMaximumActionCount {
            throw OKAlertError.maxAlertAction
        }
        _ = alertController.view
        alertController.setupView(message: message, actions: actions)
        return alertController
    }

    /// Sets up the view for alert
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - message: Text to be displayed on the textView
    ///   - actions: Action handlers of the buttons
    private func setupView(message: NSAttributedString, actions: [OKAlertAction]) {
        textViewMessageDisplayer.attributedText = message
        alertActions = actions

        setButtonUI()

        contraintHeightTextView.constant = textViewMessageDisplayer.contentSize.height >= contraintHeightTextView.constant ? contraintHeightTextView.constant : textViewMessageDisplayer.contentSize.height
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        handleBottomViewSetup()
    }

    /// Sets the button UI  for the alert
    private func setButtonUI() {
        guard let actions = alertActions else { return }
        for (index, action) in actions.enumerated() {
            if index < buttons.count {
                buttons[index].setAttributedTitle(action.actionText, for: .normal)
                buttons[index].isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }

    /// Handles UI for one or two buttons
    private func handleBottomViewSetup() {
        if let actions = alertActions, actions.count < OKAlertController.kMaximumActionCount {
            labelSeperator.removeFromSuperview()
            buttons.last?.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonActionHandlers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let index = buttons.index(of: sender), let actions = alertActions {
            if index < actions.count {
                let action = actions[index]
                action.actionClosure?()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of OKAlertController.getAlertController

Comment: are you trying to present a viewcontroller and presenting alert in that viewcontroller???

Comment: @Shezad No its a custom alert, its a normal uiview.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I can not unfortunately due to restrictions. But I am sure that is not messing it up as the same code called without the nested threads runs fine and interaction works properly.

Comment: You need to provide more code & context. You say it's a normal UIView, but you set the `modalPresentationStyle` property, which means it's an UIViewController - which is not a UIView. You only show the code how you create the viewcontroller (not how you present it).

Comment: @GertjanSmits Yup, my bad that... I have updated the question.

Comment: I didn't run your code, but the `OKAlertController ` seems okay. But you didn't provide code that actually uses that class. You mention threads, but I don't see that code anywhere. _"I did try to running the displaying logic on main thread but that did not work."_ - You should **always** run UI related code on the main thread.